# solr search over ms sql server - an updated tutorial needed

Tags: sql-server, solr, sql-server-2012

I am trying to config solr over ms sql server.
I found only [this tutorial](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/lucene_solr_sql_server) which is a bit old (2011)
Is there an updated  tutorial? 
Is there a formal tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Steps to configure solr on Tomcat

http://zensarteam.wordpress.com/2011/11/25/6-steps-to-configure-solr-on-apache-tomcat-7-0-20/

Everything about data import handler can be found here..

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

After creating the dataimport handler (ex file name data-config.xml) you need to add this request handler to solrconfig.xml as below

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">/home/username/data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

**Sample ms sql DIH configuration:**

**data-config.xml:**

```
<dataConfig> 
      <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
            driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
            url="jdbc:sqlserver://myserver;databaseName=mydb;responseBuffering=adaptive;selectMethod=cursor"   
            user="sa" 
            password="password"/> 
      <document> 
        <entity name="results" query="SELECT statements"> 
          <field column="fielda" name="fielda"/>
    <field column="fieldb" name="fieldb"/>
    <field column="fieldc" name="fieldc"/> 
        </entity> 
      </document> 
    </dataConfig>
```